# Youtube embed link suddenly stopped working

Tags: youtube-api

Is there any change about the youtube embed links? They suddenly stopped working and are showing 'Video unavailable' message. I can't get them to work on any video, and they have been working before.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/3OVnl-tFJS8.

I also tried embedding the iframe youtube provides under the 'Share' option as a whole, and the videos are still unavailable